# Stuck in Powershell sqlserver

Tags: powershell

I'm a bit of a powershell newbie.

So I've created a script that uses the `Restore-SqlDatabase` commandlet. However, after I run it, it leaves Powershell in a different state.

```
PS D:\theFolder\> .\myRestoreDatabaseScript.ps1
... snip does the work ...
PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

How can I return Powershell back to the "normal" interface?

Also, what is the `PS SQLSERVER` prefix called? I tried to Google for this and came up empty.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From MS article [SQL Server PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245198.aspx)

> •A SQL Server provider, which enables a simple navigation mechanism similar to file system paths. You can build paths similar to file system paths, where the drive is associated with a SQL Server management object model, and the nodes are based on the object model classes. You can then use familiar commands such as **cd** and **dir** to navigate the paths similar to the way you navigate folders in a command prompt window. You can use other commands, such as **ren** or **del**, to perform actions on the nodes in the path.

Having a provider like this loaded allows you to treat the SQLServer the same way you would treat a drive (letter).

So most likely somewhere in your code you've used `CD` to move into the SQLServer provider (`cd sqlserver:`).

If you wanted to get back to `d:\thefolder` specifically you'd use `cd d:\thefolder`.

If you want to return to where you started when done, then you'll probably have to store the current directory location into a variable a the start of the script, and then use it with `cd` at the end of the script to change back to that original directory.

Or you could, as suggested by @alroc's in his comment, use the [`push-location`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849855.aspx) and [`pop-location`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849842.aspx) cmdlets to store and retrieve the current location.

Comment: You don't have to save the current directory to a variable; use `push-location` before importing `sqlps` and `pop-location` after importing and you're good to go.

Comment: @alroc I figured there was probably something like that, but I wasn't aware of that one. :)  Handy.

Comment: just type c: <enter>

Answer (score 7):

this seems to works for me:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\MyFolder\TestSqlCmd.sql" | out-null
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply type `C:` on command prompt, to go back to the usual (e.g. C:\>) prompt.

Just for information, what may have triggered the SMO prompt (i.e. ***PS SQLSERVER:>***) from normal ***C:\>*** prompt), is when you load the SMO assembly without the ***Out-Null*** (out-null suppresses the output returned by the cmdlet).

In other words, to avoid going inadvertently into the SMO prompt when loading the SMO assembly, simply pipe the *Out-Null* as below:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null
```

As Microsoft has deprecated the  *LoadWithPartialName()* method, use the *Add-Type* instead:

```
Add-Type -Path "your_path_to_assembly\Smo.dll"
```

Note: to get path to your assembly/dll - use the *GetAssemblies()* method as below:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ? {$_.Location -match 'Smo.dll'}
```

HTH.